# After Craft CMS v4 Update: Getting unknown property: craft\models\Volume::settings

Tags: migration, commerce4

Our staging environment update to Craft v4 seemed to work fine, but now on production we're getting this error when trying to send email confirmations after successful orders (happens in the queue job):

```
Getting unknown property: craft\models\Volume::settings 
vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154
```

It happens when order confirmation emails are being sent in the queue.
There are no useful additional infos in the logs.
We have no custom field called settings, so it must be a native field/prop.
There were no migration errors.
I've cleared the cache with no effect (1x via CMS; 1x via Console; 1x manually deleting in storage folder).
It seems this error usually happens when migrations had failed or with project config issues, but "settings" doesn't seem to be a field/column, so I'm not sure that's the issue.
I've re-saved all volumes and filesystems without effect.

Any other ideas that I can try?

Thank you!

PS: Running PHP 8.0.27, MySql 5.7, Craft CMS 4.4.7 and Commerce 4.2.6.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I've tried both of those options now, and still no change. Any other ideas? This is getting frustrating and I'm contacting craft now :(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that your migration to Craft 4 has hit a hiccup! Something I would suggest starting with is deleting the vendor folder in your project, and then re-running composer install. This will pull in a fresh copy of all those internal Craft code files.

You could also try re-applying the project config (select the from YAML files option if prompted).

This has worked for us on some minor upgrade hiccups on our sites.